# How to import loopcontrol in jinja2

Tags: python, jinja2

I need to use break for a for loop in jinja2.
Below is my code:

```
{% for i in range (0, desc) %}{{ desclist[i] }} {% set length = length + desclist[i]|length %}{% if length >= 70 %}{% break %}{% endif %}{% endfor %}
```

and to import the loopcontrol extension:

[image]

However, I got an error as followed:

```
jinja2.exceptions.TemplateSyntaxError: Encountered unknown tag 'break'.
Jinja was looking for the following tags: 'elif' or 'else' or 'endif'. The
innermost block that needs to be closed is 'if'.
```

Any idea to make this work?
Thank you.

Comment: You don't have a for loop in your code

Comment: i just edited my question

Answer (score 0):

Encountered the same issue, and realized on top of the [document](https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/en/3.1.x/extensions/#loopcontrols-extension)

it says:

> The following example creates a Jinja environment with the i18n extension loaded:
> jinja_env = Environment(extensions=['jinja2.ext.i18n'])

So I tried this and it finally resolved the error of `... Encountered unknown tag ...`:

`jinja_env = Environment(extensions=['jinja2.ext.loopcontrols'])`